# Importing node.js require modules to .html

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a complex program which involves uploading an excel sheet, creating a table and then work with the data in the table.

I must read first column of all rows and for every string, I must perform API call to the server.

The API request is performed as following:

```
async function main()
{
    var id = await GOR_login();
    console.log(id)
    var result = await Gor_completed_actions(id,"RUT240");
    console.log("emmiting result123=",result)
    
}
```

I used async and await functions to ensure that I get the result before I pass it to another function. For example GOR_login() is going to perform API GET request and if I do not use away, the data in `console.log(id)` will be undefined. I am not sure whether that is a correct way of doing.

Both API request functions GOR_login() and Gor_completed_actions are using node.js module fetch-node. I would like to call these functions in my html file after my table is being created, but I must somehow import fetch-node module to the html file.

Please check this JS fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/v04k3w7j/.

After uploading the excel document, it will create a table and fill the array codes_to_updt [] . This array tells me what API calls I need to make. After that, I must execute the function for the API calls:

```
async function main()
{
    var id = await GOR_login();
    console.log(id)

    var result = await Gor_completed_actions(id,codes_to_updt); // call with codes_to_updt one by one
    console.log("emmiting result123=",result)

}
```

The issue for me that I am not able to use fetch methods in .html file. In my .js file I do:

```
var fetch = require("node-fetch");
```

But it does not allow me to do that in .html.

Can someone clarify me what is the best solution to this problem?

**UPDATE1** I hide the URL just for security reasons

Inside my .html, I try to use the following function for my html get request:

```
function httpGetAsync(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

And then this function is being called after the my array is filled:

```
    httpGetAsync(URL_start_session);
```

The error is returned:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'my_url' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

**Trying to upload and parse the excel on node(server) side.**

I have downloaded an xlsx module and with the following code, I am able to parse the excel document:

```
var XLSX = require('xlsx')
var workbook = XLSX.readFile('gor_plan2.xlsx');
var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
var xlData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]);
console.log(xlData);
```

The console.log output returns me data:

```
[
  { Produkto_kodas: 'Product1', Kiekis: 50 },
  { Produkto_kodas: 'Product2', Kiekis: 295 },
  { Produkto_kodas: 'Product3', Kiekis: 244 },
  { Produkto_kodas: 'Product4', Kiekis: 225 },
  { Produkto_kodas: 'Product5', Kiekis: 17 }
]
```

Now I try to build a table out of this data.

How can I convert the JSON object data xlData into something html like :

```
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Produkto kodas</th>
            <th>Kiekis</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product1</td>
            <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Product2</td>
            <td>295</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Product3</td>
            <td>244</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Product4</td>
            <td>225</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Product5</td>
            <td>17</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I have tried something and updated my initial question see UPDATE1. I am still researching and looking for solution to this.

Comment: I have been reading about it. Which means I must somehow route it through my backend. I do not have any control of the server I am making requests to and I am sure they are not going to change their settings. Would you be able to point me to the right direction how can this be done since we know routing from frontend wont work?

Comment: What do you use as backend?

Comment: As backend I use node with websockets. The whole idea of this webpage is to upload an excel and then based on strings detected, make requests to the server which is going to return some data and then I must fill the table with that data. Everything must be done in real time - upload excel once, and once it is uploaded, I am going to make requests every 5 minutes to check whether the data on the server hasnt changed, if it changed, I must update my table and display new data to all connected clients.

Comment: I do actually use express. So in my .html I can read the table and determine what requests I need to perform. The data is saved here ```for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) 
    {
        var firstCol = table.rows[i].cells[0]; //first column
        codes_to_updt.push(firstCol.innerHTML);
    }```. The concern is how can I transfer this variable (coes_to_updt) to my JS? If I have this variable in my JS file, I can easily parse this array and build my URL for HTML requests with node-fetch.

Comment: Ok, so you have an array of strings. Make a fetch POST request, set header `Content-type: application/json` and provide `JSON.stringify(codes_to_updt)` as `body`. In express you need `app.use(bodyparser.json());` or similar at the top to enable parsing of JSON. In the express route to which you send this, use Promise.all or a for / await loop to run all requests. then res.json(result) at the end. (Note that all of these individual parts are asked an answered, *especially* right here on SO)

Comment: Thats way too much information for now. I try to do this step by step. In my server.js I call ```GOR_login(); //this must be executed only after the table is fully parsed``` this GOR_login function must be executed after the table has been created. After the table is created, I then create a variable in my .html called ```var=ID```, I must then pass this ID to the GOR_login function and ensure that it happens once the table has been fully parsed. I am working on this part for now. I am gatgering information I hope I can find how to send my variable from html to .js

Comment: Note that it's probably easier to just upload the excel doc and parse it node-side.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am now thinking about 2 possible solutions. 1. Parsing the excel on the node side. 2. Use the database. For example store the table data after parsing in the database, and then on the server side, I should be able to access this database and read what strings are stored there. Im thinking it would be best to use database so I can always store the updated table there. For example when the website is refreshed, I do not want to serve the default index.html, I want to serve the table since it was already uploaded before the refresh.

Comment: No, there's no document on the server. There's two common ways. 1) The old one: send back an HTML string (either by composing it manually, using a server-side DOM library or a view engine). 2) The current one: send back just the data in JSON format, parse it back into an array on the client-side and build the table.

Comment: Yeah I am able to parse it and the data returned is in JSON format. I have updated my initial question for more details. I am now trying to encode what you meant by "parse it back into an array on the client-side and build the table."

Comment: Didn't you say you need to run requests based on the Excel data?

Comment: Anyway, here's how to build a table from a data array: https://jsfiddle.net/1xjhpqLn/

Comment: I tried to copy this buildTable function to my server.js. The error :```ReferenceError: userTable is not defined
```. Am I not understanding something? I thought I parse my excel table in my server.js file and then I have the array of json data ( I assume it is same as users  = []  in your example). Then I call your function with that array

Comment: Sorry, no. The code I showed you clearly runs in an browser, doesn't it? It's supposed to show how to build a table client-side, after fetching the table data from the server. `userTable` references the <tbody> element from the HTML section.

Comment: Again, if you have successfully extracted the table date in your server.js, the next step is to run those API requests, one for each table row, correct?

Comment: Yes. But my most concerning part is after I have made all the requests, I have the data that I need to put into the table. If I understand it correctly, the server.js is not able to do that, I must do this in the .html file. How do I transfer all this data that I have gathered in server.js and serve it to .html so it can update my table? I have come from embedded programming background and I still cant get my head arround the fact that .html and .js are like 2 seperate things and they dont share information between each other easily...

Comment: For example after I have parsed the excel table in my server.js and have saved all the data in the variable xlData ( See my initial question for more details). How do I then use this JSON data to build my table ? Since I must do this in html but my html has no idea about existence of this variable

Comment: They don't share information at all, and HTML isn't a programming language. You have node and express, so you can just do something like `res.send("<p>Hello World</p>");` at the end of your route handler. If you request that in your client-side script, you can just insert that into your HTML document. What you are going to do is compile all the server data you need, then finally use `res.json(theData)`. In your client-side script you do exactly what I demonstrated: call .json() on the fetch response to get the server data back as object, then build a table from it.

Comment: Like I said, your server doesn't know or care it's dealing with HTML if you choose that route. You could just compose a big string on the server that happens to be an HTML table, and send that back. That is what people used to do, and it's why the old request object is called XMLHttpRequest: people composed XML strings on the server and sent them back. Also, like I said: if you set up a view engine in express, you can use a templating system like ejs or pug to build the table.

Comment: I have updated my initial question. Could you please show me an example of how can I use this JSON object that I have obtained from reading the excel document, convert this to html table and send it to my .html file? Most suggestions I see online involve using Jade module. I will try to read about it and see if I can use it on my project.

Comment: 1. there's no such thing as a JSON object. It's either JSON (text/string), or it's an Object/Array. 2. yes, use pug's iteration: https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html But again, you can simply put your array into `res.json()` and use pretty much exactly the code from the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for all the information. Before I try something else, I am trying the database approach. Does the following make sense to you? My server.js is going to parse the table handle all the requests. Then my server.js is going to create MYSQL table and insert data there. It is then going to perform periodical requests to the server and UPDATE mysql database if necessary. The only thing that HTML will do, is just serve this database to the clients as a table. I have found how its possible to do so using php https://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_mysqli_connect_error.asp.

Comment: This seems like the most appropriate solution as I wont need to worry about sharing information between HTML and JS. I simply can do everything through the database

Comment: First and foremost, [please stay away from w3schools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com) (and don't link to it, especially not from here). Your approach sounds fine I guess. Except that again, HTML doesn't really *do* anything. It's completely passive. It's not a programming language. It cannot serve anything. It cannot make requests. It cannot use a database. But yes, writing a PHP script that grabs information from the DB and uses a loop to echo an HTML table sounds like a sensible, basic approach.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I am now learning and reading more about node.js and PHP. I have read somewhere that it may not be good idea to use PHP script in application running node.js. Is that correct? For example if there is a php script to connect to db and echo the data to the client page, there must be the same method to do that without using php. Maybe as you mentioned of using res or something like that

Comment: PHP and nodeJS are competitors, if you will. You use one or the other, not both. As a webdev beginner, learning PHP is way easier because you just link to `/data_table.php` in your index.php, then write a data_table.php script to make it a) load database rows b) print an HTML document. node.js can of course do the same thing but unless you have a solid grasp of HTTP basics, better use PHP to learn them, not node. Start here maybe: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-get-started.php

Comment: Okay il read now more about the php.. So just clear things out : I need to abandon the idea of using PHP script in my html if I am using node right? I have tried it and I am facing the problem that the server is not able to parse the php script properly. It is escaping the script and just displaying the code. Or it is still possible to have most of the things running on node.js and just using the simple PHP script to echo the table from the mysql

Comment: Yeah, putting PHP in between your HTML (and using .php as extension) only works if you have PHP installed and your web server set up to use it. The php file has to be pre-processed by php.exe, which actually runs the stuff inside <?php ?>. I'd get [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) for that. (and ditch node for now)

Comment: What about using it with .html as extension? I chose node.js because it seemed like the most popular solution and from what I heard you can handle websockets very well with it, but now I realise I may not be capable of handling all that information. Perhaps I should begin from the start and use php instead

Comment: When you use a default setup of Apache and PHP, .html files are served as-is and .php files are preprocessed by PHP before they are served. So if you put <?php ... ?> inside your HTML, you have to change the file extension to .php. (although you *can* use SEO-urls if you want)  Node is not exactly easier to use, just different, but the websockets point is true. With PHP, requests are handled by the server itself (apache/nginx/etc) which then runs PHP over .php files once and sends back the result. A Node server does both: handle the request, run server-side code, and send back the result.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't import Node modules on PureJS. But you can try calling a NodeJS function like this:

Note: I'm using express.js, hope this is not a problem for you.

```
//index.js
const expressjs = require("express")
const app = expressjs();

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
   res.render("index.html");
});
app.get("/resources", (req, res) => {
   func()
});

function func() {
   var XLSX = require("xlsx")
}

app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log("Listening")
}
```

HTML Server-Side:

```
<script>
    var url = "http://ip:port/resources"
        async function nodecall() {
            fetch(url)
        }
</script>
<button id="tap" onclick="nodecall()">Call NodeJS</button>
```

If you want to pass a variable from server-side to client-side you can do something like this:

NodeJs:

```
app.get("/resources", (req, res) => {
   var variable = req.query.var
   var variable2 = req.query.var2
});
```

HTML:

```
var url = "http://ip:port/resources?var=hello&var2=world"
```

And if you want to do the opposite. Client to Server...

NodeJs:

```
app.get("/resources", (req, res) => {
   var string = "Hello World"
   return res.send(string)
});
```

HTML:

```
let variable = await(await fetch(url)).text()
```

Remember to put HTML files in a folder named "views".

You can combine all of them if you want to. Hope this helped. Bye!